# Literature on ascetic philosophy

Tags: reference-request

wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. I am a high school student exploring a possible topic on Ethan Frome for literature class. I am trying to understand Ethan's moral values through what I see as asceticism. What should I read?

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite readable book by Richard Finn OP titled *Asceticism in the Graeco-Roman World*. It is a wonderful source of historical accounts of asceticism and of, most importantly, the practices which characterize, or in many cases have characterized, the different currents of this latter.

I think this book gives you a good overview on what asceticism has meant for many different cultures and sects, that is, it gives you the big, historical picture.

If you want something more *theorico-philosophical*, I would agree on F. Nietzsche (I would recommed *Thus spoke Zarathustra* in this specific case) but also the Neoplatonical Corpus is heavily oriented towards self-denial and the restrain of the worldly. I think any good book on Plotinus, such as [this book by Pierre Hadot](https://books.google.de/books/about/Plotinus_Or_the_Simplicity_of_Vision.html?id=8btzl8RaKR8C&hl=en) (one of the best, in my opinion), would give you a good exposition of the main ascetic tenets of early Neoplatonism.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Ethan Frome, but Nietzsche famously had a lot to say about the asceticism. His most developed thoughts on the matter are in *On the Genealogy of Morality*, specifically in Part 3, which is devoted to understanding what he calls the "ascetic ideal".

Answer (score 0):

Theres an essay by Foucault, which he called *Technologies of the soul*, where he ties together Christian, and Graeco-Roman notions of the self which you might find useful.